# Get Entries from a specific Entry Type

Tags: plugin-development, sections, entry-type

I'm trying to get all Entries that are from a specific Entry Type.

My Section is "Site".
Which has 3 different Entry Types.

Now I want to get all Entries from the Entry Type "Program".

I'm trying to reach my goal with `Craft::$app->sections->` or `Craft::$app->elements->`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$entries = Entry::find()->section('sectionHandle')->type(['yourTypeHandle'])->all();
```